# Vue warn : Error in render: "TypeError: route is undefined"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Good afternoon!
Can you tell me what the error is?
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of code/errors/data. Instead post the code/errors/data as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your router folder in `index.js` add

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";

Vue.use(VueRouter);
export default new Router({
   //routes of components
})
```

And then in your `main.js` remove

```
Vue.use(VueRouter);
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Please do upvote the answer. So it may help others too